# Quasar: build with development mode

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, quasar-framework, quasar

I have in quasar.conf.js env settings with something like this:

```
env: {
  API_URL: ctx.dev
    ? 'https://dev.apis.test.io/v2/'
    : 'https://apis.test.io/v2/'
}
```

When I run app on local host dev api is used, when I run `quasar build` production api is used. So that is working.
How can I build with dev env settings?

For example on plain Vue `yarn build --mode development` works just fine. How can I do the same thing with quasar?

I tried:

`quasar build --mode development`

`quasar build --mode dev`

`quasar build --development`

`quasar build --dev`

`quasar build --debug`

and I always get production link in dist folder files

Answer (score 8):

the answer above is not really wrong. You can do something like this:

1. create multiple .env files, for me best option is:

   ```
   .env.local
   .env.development
   .env.production
   ```
2. inside `quasar.conf.js` use `dotenv` library:

```
  const env = require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.ENV_FILE.toLowerCase()}` }).parsed
```

3. then put vars to quasar env:

```
    build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'history', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
      env: {
        ...env
      },
```

4. then run build for production or stage or run dev server with command:

```
ENV_FILE=development quasar build
```

For me it works like a charm, because i have more than two envs

Comment: Yes, at the end I used this instructions https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env#using-dotenv which I presume is what you did too.

Comment: As for now it's the best solution in the whole internet, thank you :)

Comment: This should definitely be marked as the accepted answer. Solves the problem and simply enough.. with the little caveat of having to use the right command to set the environment variable depending on the OS of the machine running it. You can even use this flow with quasar dev and test locally.

Answer (score 1):

By December 2023.

[**Adding to process.env**](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/handling-process-env#adding-to-process-env)

You can add your own definitions to process.env through the the */quasar.config* file.

It’s important to understand the different types of environment variables.

1. The env variables from the terminal that are defined in the
   */quasar.config file*.
2. The environment variables that you pass to your UI code. then we pick
   it up in the */quasar.config file*

....

```
// Accessing terminal variables
console.log(process.env)

module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
    // ...

    build: {
      // passing down to UI code from the quasar.config file
      env: {
        API: ctx.dev
          ? 'https://dev.api.com'
          : 'https://prod.api.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your *website/app*, you can access *process∙env∙API*, and it will point to one of those two links above, depending on dev or production build type.

You can even combine it with values from the *quasar dev/build* env variables:

```
# we set an env variable in terminal
$ MY_API=api.com quasar build


// then we pick it up in the /quasar.config file
build: {
  env: {
    API: ctx.dev
      ? 'https://dev.' + process.env.MY_API
      : 'https://prod.' + process.env.MY_API
  }
}
```

[**If you want a production build with debugging enabled:**](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-spa/build-commands#introduction)

```
quasar build -d

# ..or the longer form
quasar build --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

try run
MY_API=api.com quasar build

Comment: If I understand this command correctly it will only cover one variable - API. But I will have multiple variables in env object, so I need command that will use all variables in dev mode, not just one.